# Нужно ли наращение в сокращенной записи года?

Tags: орфография, числительные, наращение, даты

Наращения не требуются в датах. Касается ли это и сокращенной записи приводимого года? Например: *94 год в России*.

Answer (score 3):

*Наращения не требуются в датах.*
Не-не, так категорически говорить нельзя.
Если слово "год" пропущено или стоит перед цифрой, то в порядковых числительных, обозначающих даты, **требуется** наращение:
подготовка начнется весной 2018-го; неприятности посыпались году в 1990-м.

Думаю, что если имеется в виду дата в сокращенном варианте (со словом "год"), то наращение все-таки **не нужно** (есть тысяча девятьсот или нет — дата все равно остается датой):
1994 год в России (в 1994 году) = 94 год в России (в 94 году).

***93 год** был годом величайшего напряжения* (В. Гюго. Девяносто третий год). [Подразумевается 1793 год.]

*В течение восьми лет (вплоть до моего отъезда из Петербурга весной **17 года**) я встречался с ним в редакции «Аполлона»* ([О. Мандельштам. Шум времени](https://books.google.ee/books?id=QPrx037ht4EC&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=%22%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%2017%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%22&source=bl&ots=-yobA38ZH5&sig=ACfU3U0eo3hwU639U78O7nFWVVVi88U49w&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj604LduovyAhUImIsKHY7dAJwQ6AEwEnoECBUQAw#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%2017%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%22&f=false)).

*Ради этой цели тотчас после февральского переворота весной **17 года** была организована «Свободная ассоциация для развития и распространения положительных* (М. Уральский. Горький и евреи).

[Отсутствие наращения падежного окончания](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)

Comment: Умно, Риммчонка, умно да мудро-с.

Comment: Спасибо. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PktdYYD8d9c)

Answer (score 0):

***[Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)***

---

***[Факторы выбора словесной или цифровой формы числительных](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091464.html)***

---

И цитата из [моего ответа](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1514821-kak-pravilno-oboznachit-padezh-imjon-chislitelnyh-napisannyh-chislom-sm.html):

> ... в этих примерах не указан ещё один случай, есть "грянул 1917 год",
> есть "грянул 1917-й", но нет
>
> "грянул 17-й год", - без тысяча девятьсот! Даже если без "тысячи",
> наращение делается: "грянул 917-й год"!