# Например, в 34/34-м что-то, наверное, произошло

Tags: орфография

Мы знаем, что с годами, если есть слово *год*, мы не пишем наращения, напр.: *в 1987 году, перед 2008 годом, о 3879 годе*. Но если мы опускаем первые две цифры, так как век уже читателю исвестен, то нужны ли наращения? Как правильно?

`XI век был колоссальным. Например, в 34/34-м году что-то, наверное, произошло и было, наверное, какое-н. происшествие таки громоздкое.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите [здесь, в похожем вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467049/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

На основе этого можно сделать вывод, что наращение не нужно:

***XI век был колоссальным. Например, в 34 году что-то, наверное, произошло и было, наверное, какое-н. происшествие таки громоздкое***.

Я **полностью согласен с той, кто ответила человеку, который в ссылке**.

Comment: Интересно девки пляшут! Ответик мой использовали по полной программе... Полностью согласны... Требую плюсища!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Хм... Можете вставить свой ответ снова. Пусть ваш примет, хотя бы по-честному будет.